# tree grid view with different child columns?

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, trigger

Is it possible to show child rows with additional columns in [`tree-grid`](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/tree-grid/) 
 view component?

[image]

when expanding the account I need contact's emailId column.

Comment: Honestly I think this will not be a good UX. The columns are guided from your outer table, and let's say even if you are able to achieve another column within the child row, I am not sure how that will look or impact your outer table's columns. One way here if you want to show additional details is to be able to utilize something as outlined in [this datatables example](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll check it out.